# Unix-Shell Scripting

Tags: unix

I have a sample file in the below format

```
Name Description Value
ram ABC 0
sri DEF 0
arjun DEF 5
```

If the 3rd column $3 contains a value other than 0, need to generate an email.

I can pick the contents of column 3 using `awk '{print $3}' file_name`.

Need someone to help me beyond this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  What does the email need to contain?  Who should it be sent to?  Which mail sending agent are you planning to use?  How would you test that the value in `$3` is not zero in `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$3!=0{system("mail -s "Subject" member@body.com");}' your_file
```